# How to fix Tic Tac Toe winner determination

Tags: java, arrays, draw, tic-tac-toe

Every time I run my Tic Tac Toe program I can create the board and do my first turn.

After the first turn, the game just ends as: "`IT'S A DRAW`", which is one of the three ending possibilities. This just happens before the computer can even make his own turn.

Another problem in my program is that the scanner user input limit(er) is not working (at the end of the code). If user inputs i.e a letter instead of int, the program crashes.

```
package newtictactoe;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class NewTicTacToe {

public static final int DRAW = 0;
public static final int COMPUTER = 1;
public static final int PLAYER = 2;

public static int size;
public static char[][] board;
public static int score = 0;
public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

/**
 * Creates base for the game.
 *
 * @param args the command line parameters. Not used.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Select board size");
    System.out.print("[int]: ");
    size = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

    board = new char[size][size];
    setupBoard();

    int i = 1;

    loop:
    while (true) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            displayBoard();
            getMove();
        } else {
            computerTurn();
        }
        switch (isGameFinished()) {
            case PLAYER:
                System.err.println("YOU WIN!");
                break loop;
            case COMPUTER:
                System.err.println("Computer WINS!\nYOU LOOSE!!");
                break loop;
            case DRAW:
                System.err.println("IT'S A DRAW");
                break loop;
        }

        i++;
    }
}

private static int isGameFinished() {
    if (isDraw()) {
        return DRAW;
    } else if (computerHasWon()) {
        return COMPUTER;
    } else if (playerHasWon()) {
        return PLAYER;
    }
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Checks for computer's win.
 *
 * @return if this game is won by computer.
 */
public static boolean playerHasWon() {
    boolean hasWon = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            // check if 5 in a line
        }
    }

    return hasWon;
}

/**
 * Checks for player's win.
 *
 * @return if this game is won by computer.
 */
public static boolean computerHasWon() {
    boolean hasWon = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            // check if 5 in a line
        }
    }

    return hasWon;
}

/**
 * Checks for draws.
 *
 * @return if this game is a draw
 */
public static boolean isDraw() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == ' ') {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Displays the board.
 *
 *
 */
public static void displayBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            System.out.printf("[%s]", board[i][j]);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}

/**
 * Displays the board.
 *
 *
 */
public static void setupBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            board[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Checks if the move is allowed. 
 *
 *
 */
public static void getMove() {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.printf("ROW: [0-%d]: ", size - 1);
        int x = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.printf("COL: [0-%d]: ", size - 1);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        if (isValidPlay(x, y)) {
            board[x][y] = 'X';
            break;
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Randomizes computer's turn - where it inputs the mark 'O'.
 *
 *
 */
public static void computerTurn() {
    Random rgen = new Random();  // Random number generator   

    while (true) {
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * size);
        int y = (int) (Math.random() * size);

        if (isValidPlay(x, y)) {
            board[x][y] = 'O';
            break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Checks if the move is possible.
 *
 * @param inX
 * @param inY
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isValidPlay(int inX, int inY) {

    // Play is out of bounds and thus not valid.
    if ((inX >= size) || (inY >= size)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Checks if a play have already been made at the location,
    // and the location is thus invalid.  
    return (board[inX][inY] == ' ');
}
```

These last two methods in the code check if the scanner input is valid but they don't work and I don't know why.

```
/**
 * Checks if user input is valid
 *
 * @param scan
 * @param prompt
 * @return
 */
public static String getInput(Scanner scan, String prompt) {
    System.out.print(prompt); // Tell user what to input
    String text = "Enter one integer value i.e 5.";
    while (true) { // Keeps on looping until valid input
        text = scan.nextLine();
        if (isInteger(text)) // Checks input is int
        {
            break; // Exit loop
        }
        System.out.print("Try again, " + prompt); // If invalid
    }
    return text; // Return valid user input
}

/**
 * Checks if input string is int.
 *
 * @param str
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isInteger(String str) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(str); // If this succeeds the input is int
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false; // If not int
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `isGameFinished()` method returns 0 by default (when the game is not over), but your `DRAW` constant is also 0. Try to change it to return (for example) -1 when the game is not over.

A nicer solution would be to have one method `isGameFinished()` that would return `boolean` to indicate if the game is over, and another method `getWinner()` which would return the winner (DRAW or COMPUTER or PLAYER), and will only be called if `isGameFinished()` returns true.

Your `getMove` method should catch NumberFormatException, which can be thrown by `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: I changed it to -1 and now the game can end, but only as a draw. Thanks for the tip. + Don't i  have the `Integer.parseInt` in the `getMove` already? In the `int x` and `int y`.

Comment: @jjimih 1. Your `playerHasWon` and `computerHasWon` are not done, so they always return false. 2. You do have `Integer.parseInt`, but you are not catching the exception that may be thrown if the input is not a number.